# Games With No Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

In our Game Theory class, we're learning about subgame perfect Nash equilibria (SPNE) for finite extensive form games. Our professor mentioned that not all games have a pure SPNE. I think that the only type of game to not have a pure SPNE would be one of imperfect information, but aren't all games subgames of themselves, so their pure NE would also be a pure SPNE?

I'd really appreciate an example of a game graph where there is no pure SPNE but there is a pure NE to help me clarify this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Even a game with perfect information can have equilibria SPNE in mixed strategies (e.g., assume identical payoffs in all terminal nodes), but it is correct that only games with imperfect information *may not* have SPNE in pure strategies.

The simplest example of all is obtained if you take a simultaneous-move game that has only a NE in mixed strategies (e.g., Matching Pennies) and write it as an extensive-form game. The extensive form has a non-trivial information set and has incomplete information. The set of NE is the same for the strategic form and for the extensive form; moreover, the NE and the SPNE for the extensive form coincide.

Comment: Based on my understanding, a game is a subgame of itself, so wouldn't the NE for matching pennies also be an SPNE? Or would it only be considered a NE in that case?

Comment: All SPNE are also NE. You can tag it both ways.